# When does $r$ divide $\binom{n}{r}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Suppose $n>r$ and both $n$ and $r$ are positive integers.

When can we have that $\dbinom{n}{r}$ is divisible by $r$ ?

I'm looking for all pairs $(n, r)$ such that the above condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this question is quite difficult. The answer for the case that $r$ is prime can be deduced from [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem), which says in particular that ${n\choose r}$ is divisibly by a prime $p$ if and only if one of the digits of $r$ when written in base $p$ is greater than the corresponding base $p$ digit of $n$.

Since $r=10_r$ written in base $r$, we obtain that

> If $r$ is prime then ${n\choose r}$ is divisible by $r$ if and only if the remainder of $n$ modulo $r^2$ is smaller than $r$.